# Delphi7 - TWebBrowser does not load web, IE or Chrome correct

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser, tembeddedwb

Using Delphi 7 on Win7, all updates.

The `TWebBrowser` component (or `TEmbeddedWebBrowser`) does not load http://www.sreality.cz correctly. Until recently, everything was ok. I think it happened after deploying multilingual websites. However, in IE or Chrome, everything is ok.

Setting [Internet Feature Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730.aspx) was unsuccessful.

Do you know the answer?

Comment: `TWebBrowser` is just a wrapper for IE's core engine, so anything the standalone IE browser can handle, `TWebBrowser` should be able to handle as well.

Comment: how does it not load correctly, please provide information

Comment: See this answer about the browser_emulation registry value, I think you don't receive most up to date IE rendering instance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494269/twebbrowser-in-windows-10-microsoft-edge-formerly-spartan-internet-explorer/30391582#30391582 (disregard this, you already tried this)